# Invalid credentials on http post with json

Tags: android, json, http-post

I tried to post on my api with Postman and all works very well. I'm using same credentials on my android application too.

The only required elements are : the header : `"X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"`and, in the body `form-data` as : `email:value` & `password:value`. The `Sresponse` string is `'invalid-credentials'` . Am i using right the JSON, the POST ?

This is my `post` method:

```
  public String requestLogin(final String username, final String password) {
    makeNewURL("login");
    Thread thread= new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                post.addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                json.accumulate("email", username);
                json.accumulate("password", password);
                StringEntity params = null;
                params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                post.setEntity(params);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                Sresponse="   "+ EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            }
            catch(Exception x){
                Sresponse=x.getMessage();
            }


        }
    });
    thread.start();

    return Sresponse;
}
```